# symfony authentication issue after username change

Tags: php, symfony

I have the fllowing problem. I have a website made in symfony 2, now after I pass the authentication form I have a profile info window when I can change the user data, eg. username.

The thing is that after I change the username the website makes me login again. How can I avoid that need to login again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username is stored in the session by symfony to load the user data (user Entity) on every page view after authentication. You are asked to log in again because the username used to authenticate is  no longer be able to load the user data. You can try updating the username stored in the session ( token ) :

```
$oldToken = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();

// create the authentication token
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
    $user, //user object with updated username
    null,
    $oldToken->getProviderKey(),
    $oldToken->getRoles());
// update the token in the security context
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Comment: Thanks David, I resolved it, the thing is that you need to re authenticate the user creating a new token based on the changed credentials, so your answer is correct, thanks again

Comment: In Symfony 2.6 onwards the service is named security.token_storage